# Trying to access the n-th element of a list gives ValueError when using .index()

Tags: python, list

I want to print 2 lists like this using the format function:

```
Planet | Distance from Sun
Mercury | 0.4 AU
Venus | 0.7 AU
Earth | 1.0 AU
Mars | 1.5 AU
Jupiter | 5.2 AU
Saturn | 9.5 AU
Uranus | 19.6 AU
Neptune | 30.0 AU
```

Here's the code:

```
planets = ["Planet", "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"]
distance = ["Distence from Sun", "0.4", "0.7", "1.0", "1.5", "5.2", "9.5", "19.6", "30.0"]

for i in range(len(planets)):
    print("{}|{}".format(planets.index(i), distance.index(i)))
```

Comment: `.index()` looks in the `list` for a value and returns the first index of that value in the list. I have a feeling you're confusing it with `planets[i]` which will get the n-th index from the list...?

Comment: jon clements is correct, you can also use enumerate to get the indexes:
`for i,ele in enumerate(planets):print("{}|{}".format(ele, distance[i]))`

Comment: Yeah it worked when I did planets[i], thanks you.

Answer (score 6):

`.index()` looks in the list for a value and returns the first index of that value in the list. If it can't find that value in the list, it raises a `ValueError` indicating it couldn't find the value - eg: you don't have `0` in the contents of your list. I have a feeling you're confusing it with `planets[i]` which will get the n-th index from the list.

However, a much simpler way is to "combine" the two lists, and print the results from them - you don't need to keep an index of what you're iterating over, just iterate over them, eg:

```
for p, d in zip(planets, distance):
    print(p, '|', d)
```

And in this case, you can avoid the `.format` as it wasn't matching your required output anyway :)

---

Given:

```
data = [1, 7, 5]
```

What is the value of the 3rd item in `data`?

```
print(data[2])
# 5
```

What is the index position of the first `7` in the list?

```
print(data.index(7))
# 1
```

What is the value of the list at the 2nd position?

```
print(data[1])
# 7
```

What's the position of the first `100` in the list?

```
print(data.index(100))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
#     data.index(100)
# ValueError: 100 is not in list
```